# Usage of delegates in CLI is different in Visual C++ 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, delegates, c++-cli

we have an implementation of a tree structure. The tree consists of nodes deriving from MachineItemNode. We implemented some filtering of nodes using the System::Func delegate. This enables us to search for a node inside the tree matching the specified derived type of MachineItemNode and a custom predicate.

The implementation below works fine with VS 2008 compiler (using .Net 3.5),
but using VS 2013 compiler (and .NET 4.0), I get a compiler error (see below)

```
public ref class MachineItemNode
{
public:
    generic <typename T> where T : MachineItemNode
    T FindFirstBelow()
    {
        System::Func<T, bool>^ filter = gcnew System::Func<T, bool>(this, &MachineItemNode::AlwaysTrue<T>);
        return FindFirstBelow<T>(filter); // error C2670: 'MachineItemNode::FindFirstBelow' : the function template cannot convert parameter 1 from type 'System::Func<T,bool> ^'
    }

    generic <typename T> where T : MachineItemNode
    T FindFirstBelow(System::Func<T, bool>^ filter)
    {
        if (this->IsNode<T>())
        {
            T result = safe_cast<T>(this);
            if (filter(result))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        for each (MachineItemNode^ child in Children)
        {
            T result = child->FindFirstBelow<T>(filter);
            if (result != nullptr)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return T();
    }

    generic <typename T> where T : MachineItemNode
        bool AlwaysTrue(T)
    {
        return true;
    }

    generic <typename T> where T : MachineItemNode
        bool IsNode()
    {
        return T::typeid->IsAssignableFrom(this->GetType());
    }

private: List<MachineItemNode^>^ Children;
};
```

From my point of view, everything should work nicely. The type of filter is exactly the one required in the parameterized version of FindFirstBelow.

Is something wrong with my code or is this a bug in the Visual Studio Compiler?

Best regards
Michael

Comment: @Petr: Obviously not.

Comment: After adding the missing declarations (do post repro code that can actually compile!) I get no complaints whatsoever from the compiler.  I didn't expect one either.  Do document *all* the errors that you get, there should also be a C2440 that's more informative.

Comment: What did you need to add? I don't have no other errors.

Comment: I change the code a little bit such that I get the C2440, by adding a helper function `GetAlwaysFilterTrue`. 
The error I get now is: error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'System::Func<T,bool> ^' to 'System::Func<T,bool> ^'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Answer (score 1):

```
 cannot convert from 'System::Func<T,bool> ^' to 'System::Func<T,bool> ^
```

The diagnostic here is that you have *two* definitions for System::Func<>, they came from different assemblies.  That's possible since .NET 4.5, they moved the type from System.Core.dll to mscorlib.dll.  There's a pretty slick mechanism to make that rather breaking change invisible, the reference assemblies you use to build your project contains a [TypeForwardTo] directive to tell the compiler that it lives in another building.

But this will break like this when you don't use the correct reference assemblies.  A mishap that's not entirely uncommon in a C++/CLI project.  It goes wrong when the compiler actually uses an assembly from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework instead of the correct one, stored in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\ .NETFramework\vx.y (where x.y is the target framework).  Exactly how programmers get into this kind of trouble is not very clear to me, they never tell.

First thing to do is check the project's reference assemblies, use Project > Properties > Common Properties > References and select the assemblies listed in the References box one by one.  Verify the displayed "Relative Path" property.  Remove the reference and add it back when it is wrong.  Watch out for still having a reference to the 3.5 version of System.Core

Next thing to do is check your source code for `#using` directives.  That's brittle and has a knack to pick up the assembly from the wrong directory.  Favor using the project config instead.  Beware that #using is buried inside .h files stored in the compiler's include/msclr directory so also review your #includes.

And mscorlib.dll is problematic, note how it is not explicitly listed in the project's Reference list.  Generate a verbose build trace with Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity = Detailed.  Rebuild the project and search the build trace in the Output window for "mscorlib".

Comment: This could be the reason, but unfortunately to me it looks like mscorlib is resolved correctly. Furthermore, there is no direct reference to System.Core. Below you find the detailed build log..........

1>  Unified primary reference "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
1>      Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll".

Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Not without seeing your project or the build trace.  We do try to avoid relying on clairvoyancy here.